# Angular formArray doesn't render working mat-radio-group

Tags: angular, formarray

These are form elements that don't work properly with the formArray. They render, but clicking on a button does nothing. The editChoice() event does not seem to happen if I put a break point in it.

The controls also don't change their button state visibly.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="dialogContent">
    <ng-container formArrayName="choices">
        <div class="control" *ngFor="let value of myForm.controls.choices?.value; let i=index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                 <label class="req" [id]="choiceList[i].id + '_label'">
                      {{ choiceList[i].label }}
                 </label>
                 <mat-radio-group attr.aria-label="{{choiceList[i].label}}" 
                  attr.index="{{i}}" 
                  formControlName="choice" [value]=choiceList[i].value?
                  (click)="editChoice($event)"
                  attr.aria-labelledby="{{choiceList[i].id + '_label'}}">
                       <mat-radio-button value="Y">Yes</mat-radio-button>
                       <mat-radio-button value="N">No</mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-radio-group>
             </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

In constructor (or in ngInit, it doesn't seem to matter):

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    otherControl: [''],
    otherDescription: [''],
    electronicSignature : ['', [Validators.required]],
    choices: this.fb.array([]) 
});
```

array to be rendered:

```
choiceList: Array<any> = [
   {
       value: "Y",
       id: "choiceA",
       label: "Choice A Text"
   },{
       value: "N",
       id: "choiceB",
       label: "Choice B Text"
    } 
    //(and several more like this)
];
```

in ngInit:

```
const choices = this.myForm.controls.choices as FormArray;
for (let i=0; i < this.choiceList.length; i++) {
    choices.push(this.fb.group ({ 
        choice: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }));
}
```

There are no debug errors, unless there is some way to turn something on to not hide whatever is wrong.

Comment: This looks weird: formControlName="choice" [value]=choiceList[i].value?
                  (click)="editChoice($event)"

Comment: If I leave any of this off it still doesn't work. I got this from a working example, anyway.

formControlName="choice" [value]=choiceList[i].value? (click)="editChoice($event)"

Comment: I meant, this bit doesn’t have quotes and ends with a ? [value]=choiceList[i].value? - try [value]=“choiceList[i].value”

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the for loop in your template is cause the issue, when you loop over `myForm.controls.choices?.controls` instead of `myForm.controls.choices?.value` it works.

I can't really tell you why it isn't working so hoping someone can jump in to explain what's happening here.

Comment: Can someone point to a working example, at least. I can get Angular to work in loops with ordinary controls such as basic radio buttons, but it seems to mess up with more complex items like the mat-design stuff

Comment: I copied your complete example and switched `value` to `controls` and this works for me, maybe there is some other bug in your code?

Comment: Could you click on the controls? They render but don't work.

Comment: yes, with the `value` it rendered but didn't work but with `controls` it worked like it should

Comment: I think my problem was that I had non-controls in the array list. I later got something like this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It also helps to have a function on the typescript side that returns the object as a FormArray. When you get it by myForm.controls.choices it is typed as a control.

```
getChoices(): FormArray { 
   return myForm.controls.choices as FormArray; 
}
```